# why is message_id_equals method missing in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-relation

I seem to have this error, and I'm not doing anything special:

```
NameError (undefined method `message_id_equals' for class `ActiveRecord::Relation')
```

Why?  Here is the context:

```
@user_has_message = UserHasMessages.user_id_is(current_user.id).message_id_is(@message.id)

irb(main):012:0> UserHasMessages
=> UserHasMessages(id: integer, user_id: integer, message_id: integer, is_sender: boolean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Comment: Please post the relevant pieces of your UserHasMessages class.

Comment: @mikeonrails -- you mean the attributes?  I output them from the console in the snippet above...let me know...thanks!  I thought rd_searchlogic should allow me to do this.... :(

Comment: I've never seen `user_id_is` or anything like that. Where is that defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't chain those together like that.  You're called user_id_is on UserHasMessages, which returns an ActiveRecord response which doesn't contain a method for message_id_is. I don't really know what these methods are, but my guess is that they aren't scopes or it would allow you to chain like that.

Can't you do:

```
@user_has_message = UserHasMessages.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :message_id => @message.id)
```

To get the same effect?